# Debug after a POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, netbeans

I'd like to debug my app step-by-step to see what happens AFTER the form submission (only via POST).

The problem is the URL after submission is the same than the one before, and I do not know any way to tell the debugger to wait for the submission of the form...

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: you need to post a lot more information. Are you using an IDE? What language are you working in?

Comment: hi, I guess the title is explicit enough ;)
Netbeans ?
Rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Guides of Ruby on Rails, there is a description how to debug rails:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-ruby-debug